# Связь между таблицами MySQL / TypeORM

Tags: javascript, mysql, postman, nestjs, typeorm

недавно начал изучать TypeORM и столкнулся с такой проблемой
Есть 2 таблицы **Post** и **PostMedia**, **Post** - запись в которой присутствует информация и 2 ссылки на файлы из таблицы PostMedia, **PostMedia** - таблица в которой сохранены метаданные и ссылка на файлы. Как правильно связать эти 2 таблицы, чтобы в 1м посту можно было ссылаться на вторую таблицу дважды? (колонки *preview* и *media*)
Сейчас после перезагрузки приложение, все данные стираются

```
@Entity()
export class Posts {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  title: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  description: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  link: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  publish: boolean;

  @OneToOne(() => PostMedia, (media) => media.post)
  @JoinColumn()
  media: PostMedia;

  @OneToOne(() => PostMedia, (media) => media.post)
  @JoinColumn()
  preview: PostMedia; 

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: string;
}
```

И PostMedia

```
@Entity()
export class PostMedia {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  url: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  mime: string;

  @OneToOne(() => Post)
  post: Post;
  //...other columns

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: string;
}
```

Comment: @nörbörnën, думал чтобы айдишник от PostMedia в Post устанавливался, к примеру: previewId и mediaId, эти две ссылки ссылались на PostMedia.id соответствующих записей. Были еще варианты создать дополнительную колонку с типом для фронта ( type = "media | preview" ) и сделать OneToMany, или же разделить на 2 таблицы. Это если нет такой возможности как описал изначально

Comment: А зачем дважды? Одной ссылки достаточно)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin может я туплю) Вы имеете ввиду OneToMany? у меня в голове что-то засело это previewId и mediaId))

Comment: Я не знаю, если одному посту соответствует один медиа,  то один ко одному. Не понимаю в чем суть PostMedia

Comment: @AlexanderChernin суть PostMedia это хранения информации об файлах (их название url, mime и т.д), Мне нужно при создании поста реализовать функционал добавления превью (картинка) и видео при переходе на страницу поста открывается видео, вот чтобы создать пост нужно указать информацию (это Post) и превьюшку и видео которое по идее должно храниться в отдельном одном хранилище - PostMedia и когда мы извлекаем все посты, должна извлекаться информация о посте (из Post) и 2 файла превью и видео из (PostMedia). Такая задумка изначально была

Comment: пусть будут две колонки, одна для превью, вторая для видео и связь OneToOne. В Post одно поле PostMedia. а в коде проверяйте если задано первое поле показывайте превью, второе - видео